# Does the where utility of Windows search only the system path, not the current terminal path?

Tags: windows, command-line

I'm writing a Makefile in Windows and I'm trying to find the folder where `arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe` is installed in my system so if that changes my Makefiles won't break.

I'm trying to use `where` to get the full path for the compiler, but I noticed an odd behaviour: it seems it searches on the system `PATH` variable, not on the current terminal PATH variable. They will be different as I'm manually adding the folder where `arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe` is installed.

The idea is that the PATH variable seen by the Makefiles might be set by another script prior to calling my them and thus the system and the current terminal PATH might be different.

I don't using `setx` is a possible solution as I don't want to permanently change the system path, I just need the compiler folder added for the current shell. The final use is a build server where we have different versions of the same toolchain and I can't have them all in the system PATH.

I'll use Meld to illustrate my point. I'm adding Meld's folder to the PATH like so:

`set PATH="C:\Program Files (x86)\Meld";%PATH%`

If I call

`C:\>meld`

It surely enough opens Meld. If I check the PATH variable itself:

```
C:\>PATH
PATH="C:\Program Files (x86)\Meld";C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\mingw-w64\i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0\mingw32\bin;
```

But if I do

```
C:\>where meld
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
```

I have Mingw-W64 installed on my system , so one of the folders in my system path is `C:\mingw-w64\i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0\mingw32\bin`, so if I type

```
C:\>where gcc
C:\mingw-w64\i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0\mingw32\bin\gcc.exe
```

What gives?

Is there a way to make `where` search in the current shell's PATH variable?

To be clear: I would like `where` to behave like the POSIX `which` utility.

Thank you.

Comment: Search uses its index or where you point it to. What you are looking for here are Environment Variables (Path).  Open Advanced System Settings, Advanced and click on Environment Variables.  You can edit the Path to include the folders you would like used.

Comment: Use `setx` to set the path permanently, otherwise it is only for the current `cmd` shell.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but as I stated in my question `The idea is that this might be set by another script prior to calling my Makefiles and thus the system and the current terminal PATH might be different.`, s I can't use any type of manual editing for this.

Comment: @Leonardo - So ensure the script before the make file is ran uses *setx*

Comment: Everything, BTW, is a dandy file name search app. Has saved me a lot of grief. https://www.voidtools.com/

Comment: Your path is screwed up in at least two places.  See where it looks like Meld clobbered the path to java?  Also.. down towards the end of the path.. you have ";CC:\mingw-w64"  You don't have a "CC:\" drive ;)  You might be choking where with that nonsense.

Comment: Where works EXACTLY like you say it doesn't.  It searches the current directory and your current path.  It doesn't care if you just set it or if it came from the system.  You have another problem.  Perhaps its your messed up path.

Comment: Sorry, for the sake of brevity I edited my path, the complete thing is far longer than the one I've shown.

Comment: Please see the answer, there's no need to use `setx` or anything like that. `where` is a crappy application that doesn't like double-quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that `where` is a bad application that is picky regarding double-quotes.

If I set the PATH variable without the double-quotes around the new entry:

`set PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Meld;%PATH%`

Then `where` does find the application:

```
C:\>where meld
C:\Program Files (x86)\Meld\Meld.exe
```

If one goes to the GUI and add `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Meld"` (notice the double-quotes), the GUI remove the double-quotes.

Also notice that `setx` is potentially destructive if your PATH variable is longer then 1024 characters. `setx` destroyed my system PATH variable and I had to restore it by hand.

Answer (score 0):

The `where` command searches the current directory and the paths specified in the PATH environment variable.

You can use the `/R` switch to recursively search and display files that match the given pattern starting from the *specified* directory.  Using the `/R` switch results in the PATH environment variable *not* being searched.  For example:

> where /R c:\test *.exe

Will find all `.exe` files in `c:\test` and all of its subdirectories.  It will *not* search the PATH.

Comment: Please see my answer, it does search the current terminal's PATH. The problem was the double-quotes on Meld's PATH entry.